# Mathematica Does No Find the Global Maximum It Just Print Out My Function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, maximize

I am am mathmatica notebook to find an analytical solution to the follow constrained optimization problem:
     Max y^(1-b)(x^b(1-a(x/(x+1)))) s.t. M = Px+qy
     x,y
I have tried the following code:

```
Maximize[{y^(1-b)(x^b(1-a(x/(x+1)))), M==Px+qy}, {x,y}]
```

and in returns the same function as an output. In the function a, b, M, P, and q are all parameters. I have also tried assigning the parameters arbitrary values to test to see if mathmatica is not sure how to deal with the parameters. I used to following code:

```
Maximize[{y^(1-0.5)(x^0.5(1-0.75(x/(x+1)))), 1000=5x+5y},{x,y}]
```

and it returns the same function. However, if I remove the constraint it will solve the optimization problem.

```
Maximize[{y^(1-0.5)(x^0.5(1-0.75(x/(x+1))))},{x,y}]
{7.2912*^59,{x->2.89727*^60,y->2.93582*^60}}
```

I am not sure what to do. After reading about constrained optimization problem the syntax appears to be correct. Sorry, it this question is really basic I am very new to mathmatica, also since I am using a notebook I could not past the output from the first two lines in.

Answer (score 1):

The constraint is incorrectly specified, it should be `1000 == 5 x + 5 y`. `Maximize` works better with exact numbers.

```
Maximize[{Rationalize[y^(1 - 0.5) (x^0.5 (1 - 0.75 (x/(x + 1))))], 
   1000 == 5 x + 5 y}, {x, y}] // N

(* {25.7537, {x -> 96.97, y -> 103.03}} *)
```

Comment: Is there  ways to get Mathmatica to find the analytical solution? This is the answer that I am looking for. I have also tried using NMaximize instead of Maximize and it returns: "The following constraints are not valid {M =P x + q y} constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain specifications involving variables."

Comment: `Maximize[{Rationalize[y^(1 - 0.5) (x^0.5 (1 - 0.75 (x/(x + 1))))], 
  m == p x + q y}, {x, y}]` gives an analytical solution.